# In Farm RPG, how do I get Runestone 16

Tags: farm-rpg

I need several Runestone 16s. The hint is "it can be found with the brewers" - so I assume that means from harvesting hops. I've harvested probably 1000 hops and haven't seen one yet.

How do I get Runestone 16?